# setPadding(0,0,0,0) called several times on View after constructor

Tags: android, padding

Good evening! I'm trying to setPadding on a custom View i built and the native setPadding() did nothing so i wrote my own... After a while i realized that setPadding gets called several times after my original call and i have no idea why... Please help :) (I realize that my custom setPadding maybe quite excessive ^^)

Here is the XML containing the View. It's the PieChart.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/PieDialog_llParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PieDialog_tvHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Header"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PieDialog_tvDiv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:textSize="0sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PieDialog_tvDiv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="0sp" />

<com.SverkerSbrg.Spendo.Statistics.Piechart.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/PieDialog_Pie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PieDialog_tvDiv3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="0sp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/PieDialog_flClose"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PieDialog_tvClose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text" />

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code where i use the xml:

```
package com.SverkerSbrg.Spendo.Transaction.TransactionList.PieDialog;

imports...

public class PieDialog extends SpendoDialog{
private TransactionSet transactionSet;
private TransactionGroup transactionGroup;
private GUI_attrs gui_attrs;
private PieData pieData;

private PieChart pie;
private TextView tvHeader; 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_pie_dialog, null);

    LinearLayout llParent = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.PieDialog_llParent);
    llParent.setBackgroundColor(gui_attrs.color_Z0);

    tvHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PieDialog_tvHeader);
    tvHeader.setTextSize(gui_attrs.textSize_header);

    TextView tvDiv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PieDialog_tvDiv1);
    tvDiv1.setBackgroundColor(gui_attrs.color_Z2);

    TextView tvDiv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.PieDialog_tvDiv2);
    tvDiv2.setPadding(0, gui_attrs.padding_Z0, 0, 0);

    PieChart pie = (PieChart) view.findViewById(R.id.PieDialog_Pie);
    pie.setPadding(40, 10, 40, 10);


    builder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog ad = builder.create();

    return ad;
}
public void initialize(GUI_attrs gui_attrs, TransactionSet transactionSet, long groupIdentifier){
    this.gui_attrs = gui_attrs;
    this.transactionSet = transactionSet;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to extrapolate on my comment, it is your custom `View` object's responsibility to respect the padding that is set. You can do something like the following to make sure that you handle that case:

**onMeasure()**

```
int desiredWidth, desiredHeight;

desiredWidth = //Determine how much width you need
desiredWidth += getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();

desiredHeight = //Determine how much height you need
desiredHeight += getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

int measuredHeight, measuredWidth;

//Check against the MeasureSpec -- if it's MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, or MeasureSpec.AT_MOST
//follow those restrictions to determine the measured dimension

setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
```

**onLayout()**

```
int leftOffset = getPaddingLeft();
int topOffset = getPaddingTop();

//layout your children (if any) according to the left and top offsets,
//rather than just 0, 0
```

**onDraw()**

```
canvas.translate (getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());

//Now draw your stuff as normal
```